# ES6 transpilation is only provided in the dev module loader build, error with es6-module-loader

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-module-loader

Why would I get this error with the es6-module-loader:

`ES6 transpilation is only provided in the dev module loader build.`

here is the code that I am trying to use this with:

```
System.transpiler = 'babel';
System.import('app/main.js').then(function (module) {
  new module.Main();
});
```

main.js:

```
import foo from './foo'

export class Main {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

package.json:

```
devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.22",
    "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.6",
    "object.observe": "^0.2.4",
    "qunitjs": "^1.18.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `es6-module-loader-dev.js`.  See https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader#getting-started